# insert query not working in excel file using C#

Tags: c#, database, excel

I have executed SELECT query to get data form **.xls** (Ms-EXCEL) file
which works fine

```
 OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=XlsDB"); //Created DSN for .xls file
 con.Open();
 OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select Password from [Users$] where UserName='javed'",con);
 OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while (dr.Read())
 {
       if(dr[0].ToString()=="akram")
          MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
 }
```

**BUT**

while inserting values in **.xls** file its giving error

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("Dsn=XlsDB"); //Created DSN for .xls file
con.Open();

OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO [Users$](UserName,Password) VALUES(@name, @pass)", con);
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@name", "hello"));
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@pass", "world"));
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();  //error here
```

Comment: @Peter: `ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2.`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [system.data.odbc.odbcparameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter.aspx) and you will see that you are using the odbcparameter class incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameter names should not contain the @ symbol like...

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("name", "hello"));
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("pass", "world"));
```